# BreezeJS - Regular expression in Where Clause

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to do something like:

```
var predicate = breeze.Predicate.create('columnName', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Contains, 'regexHere');
manager.executeQuery(entityQuery.From('tableName').where(predicate));
```

It all works fine when I try to search it "normal" way, but I'd like to include regex search that would work as sql LIKE operator. Mostly, I'm interested in how to make clause similar to sqls:

```
WHERE columnName LIKE '%abc%def%'
```

Is that possible with Breeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but [FilterQueryOp.Contains], FilterQueryOp.StartsWith and FilterQueryOp.EndsWith are the closest query operators to what you want.  The OData spec that is used to construct a query url does not support regex based queries.

That said you can use *EntityQuery.withParameters* to do whatever you want with any parameters passed from a client. For example

```
// Client side
var query = EntityQuery.from("CustomersByRegex")
        .withParameters({ regex: myRegex });

// Server side
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersByRegex(string regex) {
   // use the regex here against your customers collection
   // and return the resulting customers;
}
```

You can also mix and match the two mechanisms. i.e. a regular breeze query with Filters and a 'withParamters' call.